# How to convert an tree path to a json object

Tags: java, json, tree

I have a tree with nodes like this:

```
-Root
|-Node 1
|-Node 2
  |-Node 2.1
```

one of these nodes are representet by one class

```
class Node {
    Integer id;
    String name;
    String route;
}
```

instances of the shown nodes are saved like

```
{id: 1, name: "Root", route:"1"}
{id: 2, name: "Node 1", route: "1/2"}
{id: 3, name: "Node 2", route: "1/3"}
{id: 4, name: "Node 2.1", route: "1/3/4"}
```

the question is: How can i get from a list of nodes to json representing the tree state, e.g.:

```
[{
"property": {
    "name": "Root",
    "id": "1",
    "route": "1"
},
"children": [{
    "property": {
        "name": "Node 1",
        "id": "2",
        "route": "1/2"
    },
    "property": {
        "name": "Node 2",
        "id": "3",
        "route": "1/3"
    },
    "children": [{
        "property": {
            "name": "Node 3",
            "id": "4",
            "route": "1/3/4"
        }
    }]
}]
}]
```

i need exactly this json structure

all this stuff have to be done in java. i tried to iterate over my list of nodes and built the json object, but i have problems to get the json structure from the route field of the nodes

i'm able to use a json library the node class is unchangable

EDIT: This format is quite strange, but needed. The "properties" are the nodes, if the "propertie" has children, they are not placed IN the propertie, ether AFTER the propertie... i think thats not quite sensefull but i cant change it

Comment: Freak2000 : edit your question instead of answering in the comments, it'll be much easier

Comment: Are you able to use a JSON library? Is the Node class unchangeable?

Comment: Can you explain the desired output in more detail. In my answer I assumed that each Node has children. But in your output a "property" corresponds to a Node, and it appears that a "property" doesn't have children. What is it that has children?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try an algorithm something like this:

```
public JSONObject toJSON(Node node, List<Node> others) {
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    json.put("id", node.id); // and so on
    ...
    List children = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
    for(Node subnode : others) {
        if(isChildOf(subnode, node)) {
            others.remove(subnode);
            children.add(toJSON(subnode, others));
        }
    }
    json.put("children", children);
    return json;
}
```

You are modifying a list as you iterate over it, and as recursive calls also iterate over it. This might be hairy, but try it. There are ways around it if it fails.

`isChildOf()` is the missing piece. That's some fairly basic string manipulation, to see whether subnode.path starts with node.id

Edit: actually this doesn't create the same structure as in your question. But I can't make much sense of the structure in your question. However something very similar to this algorithm will produce what you want. The principle is sound.

Comment: this does not work for me, one reason is, that each recursive method call creates a new empty json object

Comment: Well, not an *empty* JSON object. You do want to create a tree of new JSON objects - one for each of your "property" blocks. You need to adapt this algorithm to create the structure you actually want.

Comment: i don´t know how to go on... i need exactly the describet format... i know its a horrible format... but i can't change it

Answer (score 0):

You just have to parse your `route` attribute in order to make a proper graph representation.